# Script to Automatically change wallpaper when charging

Tags: gnome, scripts, desktop-background, gnome-shell-extension, charging

Is there a way to make a bash script (or gnome extension) to set an custom wallpaper when change to AC/Battery?

Comment: Start by seeing what the system logs say by observing `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect the AC, walt until the log "settles", and disconnect the AC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it in three steps. First, you need to create an udev rule. I use my mouse as an example.

/etc/udev/rules.d/99-battery.rules:

```
ACTION=="change", \
KERNEL=="hidpp_battery_0", \
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", \
ATTR{model_name}=="Performance MX", \
TAG+="systemd", \
ENV{SYSTEMD_READY}="1", \
ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}="battery@%E{POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS}.service"
```

If you make any changes to your udev rule and the device is already connected, then you must explicitly apply your rule again with `udevadm trigger`.

The easiest way to find useful attributes for your device is to start an udev monitor, connect your charging cable. Now you should see the udev path and environment attributes.

```
$ udevadm monitor --udev --environment
```

With your udev path, you can query your device for the rest of the attributes (in my case):

```
$ udevadm info -a --path='/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-3/6-3:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0006/0003:046D:101A.0007/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0'
```

Next, you need to create a systemd template. Such a service is called an "instantiated" service. It makes it possible to send a single argument via the service name. With %-specifiers, it is possible to access the "argument" within the service.

/etc/systemd/user/battery@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Logitech Battery Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/bin/battery.sh %i
```

There is no dbus method in KDE to change the background (at least that I'm aware of), so I had to use a javascript snippet.

/opt/bin/battery.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -l status=$1

[[ ! $status \
=~ (full|(dis)?charging) ]] && exit 0

if [[ $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = KDE ]]; then

javascript=$(cat << EOF
const o = {
    wallpaperPlugin: 'org.kde.image',
    currentConfigGroup: [
        'Wallpaper', 'org.kde.image', 'General'
    ]
}
for (i in (d = desktops())) {
    Object.assign(d[i], o).writeConfig('Image', 'file:///opt/wallpapers/battery_$status.png');
}
EOF
)
    busctl --user call org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell evaluateScript s "$javascript"

elif [[ $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = GNOME ]]; then

    dconf gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "'file:///opt/wallpapers/battery_$status.png'"
fi
```

The script will look for images named `battery_full.png`, `battery_charging.png`, and `battery_discharging.png` in the directory `/opt/wallpapers/`.

Comment: And it works with ubuntu and gnome? i will try it, thanks! Will post my results

Comment: think I keep this function on :)=