# Kill bash script during logout

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, logout

Probably the problem is trivial. Still I am neither able to solve it nor I found anything related on any forums. I am running a self made bash script as "start-up applications" on Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1 LTS. The script checks the battery of my laptop constantly and gives notification when it is full to avoid over-charge like:

```
while true
  check for 100% battery and play a sound 15 times
```

The problem is when I logout (and not shutting down or restarting) and log in back, I observe that there are two instances of the script, indicating that the script was not killed during log out.

The question is: what modifications do I need to kill the script during logout?

**FYI:** I have made a .desktop file to execute the script and added the .desktop file to "start-up applications".

Comment: think it would be better to use a systemd *user* timer, check your battery status and quit your script instead of a while loop.

Comment: did a similar script  [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1279842/986805) (still using it... )